# 301 Редирект в .htaccess для изображений

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

Пытаюсь настроить редирект для изображений, в связи с изменением местоположения картинок относительно корня, а также название изображений.

Пример прежнего адреса:
[http://сайт.рф/каталог/i/img_03_01.jpg](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3/i/img_03_01.jpg)

Пример нового адреса:
[http://сайт.рф/i/cat/podcat/img-03-01.jpg](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%84/i/cat/podcat/img-03-01.jpg)

Такой вид строки почему-то не работает:

RewriteRule ^каталог/i/img_([0-9]+)_([0-9]+).jpg$ i/cat/podcat/img-$1-$2.jpg [R=301,L]

Comment: Возможно кириллицу не понимает. Замените `каталог` на `[^/]+`. Если картинки у вас были только в этом каталоге, то ни каких проблем с переадресацией не должно быть.

Comment: Попробовал заменить как вы сказали, но всё по прежнему - редирект не работает

Comment: Так может у вас в .htaccess есть другие правила? Или сервер не apache?

Comment: Вот все правила из htaccess:

Comment: `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://сайт.рф/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.сайт.рф
RewriteRule (.*) http://сайт.рф/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L,QSA]`

Comment: Поменял местами порядок выполнения правил и всё заработало, благодарю за помощь